# Using aws ELB to another hosted instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I am setting up a microservice on aws, but have some server instances still on azure.

I am using path type routing for the ELB, majority of my instances are on AWS ec2, but I have a few that I still need to migrate, in the process of migrating is it possible to point the ELB paths to an external source outside aws lambda / ec2. For example to the azure server instances as well?

Comment: No. You can do that with cloudfront, but not ELB.

Comment: how would cloud front solve my issue, I have multiple servers hosting resources, my issue is not latency, but migration without downtime, as well as redundancy.

Comment: @PHPNoob CloudFront can route different paths to different backend origins, including pointing to origins outside of AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target groups support IP as well as instance ID. You can add the IP address of the Azure VMs to the target group and then have the load balancer use this target group for its condition.

Bare in mind that the IP address will need to be within the following ranges:

- 10.0.0.0/8 (RFC 1918)
- 100.64.0.0/10 (RFC 6598)
- 172.16.0.0/12 (RFC 1918)
- 192.168.0.0/16 (RFC 1918)

For this condition to be met there must be routable traffic between private IP address ranges. This would require either a VPN to be configured between networks either using the [AWS managed solution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/VPC_VPN.html) or an EC2 based VPN.

More information is available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#target-type).